# align image right and give content leaving image space

Tags: html, css, image

I want an out put similar to this [`Image`..!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlBE5.png)

following is what i've tried to do.[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4dX2/3/)

P.S: I cannot edit the structure of the content.

Comment: Is the image within the div? or is it outside of it?

Comment: within the div.. i think i forgot to close the div..please see updated  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J4dX2/3/

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/J4dX2/6/

Comment: he can not edit the html

Comment: you are going to have to use absolute positioning I believe

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't edit the HTML, you can't use floating properly, which would be the perfect solution.

But then you can use absolute positioning:

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 100px; /* image height */
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}
img {
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
p:first-child {
    max-width: 400px; /* wrapper width - image width */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4dX2/9/)